# using command find, find a directory excluding some elements

Tags: linux, shell

I have to find a directory "**Dir1**" excluding "**Dir2**" and "**Dir3**", using command find

```
$ find . -name Dir1 -type d \( -name Dir2 -o -name Dir3 \) \
         -prune -o -print
```

dosen't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move `-prune` to the beginning:

```
find . \( -name Dir2 -o -name Dir3 \) -prune -o -name Dir1 -type d
```